# Odd sizing problem in Visual Studio C# Windows Form Apps that I don't understand

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'll put it simply. The First Picture is what my designer looks like and what I want it to look like.
[GIF of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE2SE.gif)

The second gif is what it's looking like when I run it.
[GIF of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlEW8.gif)

Please help.

Changing Imagelayouts, sizes and positions. Nothing helped

Comment: Very hard to tell, because there are many ways to implement painting in WinForms. My first guess would be that's something with DPI settings, because that's mostly the root cause. So change your monitor resolution to be at a100% scale. Otherwise we need more details about how you paint your elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134946096